# Доступ API Maps Stories не существует?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как получить доступ к историям (новостям, хайлайтсам) компании для чтения или создания новых историй при помощи API Maps Stories?

Изучение документации не помогло, будто таких методов не существует вообще.

Comment: А можете как-то конкретизировать? Какие-такие "API Maps Stories" и как эти новости относятся к Картам Яндекса?

Comment: @YaCor', https://yandex.ru/maps/org/gazprombank/1325687172/ вот, например [скриншот](https://sun9-62.userapi.com/impg/mnKX0DXIcdnG0UOFPM87e59-wOQUVXaylNHVEg/ZbfgZ0vP5HA.jpg?size=1710x835&quality=96&sign=4866ee6f10ba6c5b391b6abcd4c46c15&type=album) истории и новости от Газпромбанка.
Интересует возможность добавления таких историй не через приложение или браузер, а через API скриптом.

Comment: То есть новости конкретных организаций? Это называется публикации и они относятся к Бизнесу, а не к Картам. А у Бизнеса API нет, это эксклюзив Яндекса, к которому они полный доступ целенаправленно не дают. https://yandex.ru/support/business-priority/manage/publications.html?lang=ru